# Mysql-python can't connect to localhost server on Windows 7

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows, mysql-python

i have a local mysql server running on localhost, Windows 7

```
C:\web>mysqld --console
[...]
130428 19:12:37 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.31-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

if i try to connect with mysql, i've got no issues (root has no password)

```
C:\Users\Alle>mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.5.31-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use information_schema
Database changed
mysql>
```

But when i try to connect to mysql via [MySQL-Python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) 1.2.4 this **fails**:

```
C:\Users\Alle>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'information_schema')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

here's my [conf](https://gist.github.com/apelliciari/5477587)

I'm stuck with that, i don't know what to do.. what i can do to debug the issue and get mysql-python working? I need this for Django, so i can't switch connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `127.0.0.1` instead chances are localhost is not properly mapped, or maybe you also need to include the port in your connect?

Comment: tried with port 3306 and 127.0.0.1, didn't work
i'm out of ideas

Comment: install `wamp` or `xamp` and have them run your localhost server should work for a quick fix ... no idea what the actual problem is

Comment: don't ask me why, but a windows restart solved the issue. i'm planning to delete the question, or answer to myself..

Comment: but you're right, with localhost it doesn't work now, so i need to set `127.0.0.1`